# Is morse proficiency required for UK ham license?

Tags: license, united-kingdom, morse-code

I am an Extra Class license holder who has just moved to Scotland. I am working through online training to obtain my license for here. I’m curious if Morse proficiency is a requirement for licenses here.

Answer (score 3):

There is now no Morse requirement for a UK amateur radio licence.